# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un array bidimensional con JOptionPane y que este alineado?

Tags: java, array

Buen día, mi problema es el siguiente...
Tengo un arreglo bidimensional de 4x4 y lo que quiero es mostrar el arreglo con un MessageDialog de JOptionPane donde las columnas estén alineadas.

Actualmente ya conseguí mostrar el arreglo, esto al recorrerlo por completo y guardar los datos en un String de esta manera:

```
for (int i=0;i<cifrado.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cifrado[0].length;j++){
            if(j==columnas-1){
            textocifrado=textocifrado+" | "+cifrado[i][j]+" | ";
            } else {
            textocifrado=textocifrado+" | "+cifrado[i][j];
            }
        }
        textocifrado=textocifrado+"\n";
    }
```

Pero no consigo que las columnas de este queden alineadas, entonces quedan así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar mayúsculas o números el String se desalinea aun más, aunque en la imagen no se aprecie del todo.

Ya he probado mostrar el arreglo con un JList en el message dialog, pero me da error porque solo se puede usar con arreglos unidimensionales.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de etiquetas `HTML`en conjunto con [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para convertir la matriz bidimensional en un tabla y usando usando algunas `cellspacing` darle el espacio necesario para que se vea alineado al momento de imprimirlo con el `JoptionePane`

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejemplo{
    private static void alignamentJoption(String[][]arr) {
        String output;        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html><table cellspacing=10>");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append("<tr>");
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                sb.append("<td>").append(arr[i][j]).append("</td>");//dentro de append puedes agregar "|" juega
            }
        }
        sb.append("</tr></table></html>");
        output = sb.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), output);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {    
String[][]cifrado={{"H","1","l","a"},{"h","p","l","8"},{"h","X","l","R"},{"h","O","9","a"}};    
alignamentJoption(cifrado);
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]